# How can I disable submit button after required html5 return true on the javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My html code like this :

```
<form>
    <label for="name">* Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" required><br>
    <label for="name">* Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm using `required` HTML5 attribute to validate fields.

If user does not input text, it will display HTML5 error.

I want to disable the submit button if any of the required fields are left empty.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think you might need some JS in here. There should be 'events' 
Something like when you end typing, a function is called.

Comment: So the user will never be able to submit the form?

Comment: "I want if the required html5 return true" Did you mean "return false"?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do...

Comment: @Zenoo I mean if both input text is filled, then submit button disable

Comment: @J K My question is simple. How can I disable the submit button if both input text is filled?

Comment: You mean you don't want to submit :P

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the pointer events on the button with CSS.

```css
form:invalid>#submit {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">* Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" required><br>
  <label for="name">* Address</label>
  <input type="text" id="address" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

You could also disable the button using Javascript.

```js
function disableField() {
  const invalidForm = document.querySelector('form:invalid');
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
  if (invalidForm) {
    submitBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  } else {
    submitBtn.disabled = false;
  }
}

disableField();

const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (let input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener('change', disableField);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">* Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" required><br>
  <label for="name">* Address</label>
  <input type="text" id="address" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I want to using javascript. No css

Comment: That's a good solution, I'd probably use a `for of` loop like this `for (let input of inputs)` just as it looks a little neater. https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/pnhq0ors/

Comment: @AndrewBone Yes, that is a good improvement. I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it after true

```
$("#button").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I know it. But I want to check the validation html5 first before disable the submit button

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$(function() {
$("#input-text").keyup(function () {
 if($("#input-text")[0].checkValidity()){
      $('#submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 }else{
        $('#submit-button').removeAttr('disabled');
 }
 });
})($);

<form id="newRecord">
<input type="text" required id="input-text"/>
<button form="newRecord" type="submit" id="submit-
button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

An more generic solution for multiple forms and supporting multiple inputs and buttons.

It detects the change event directly on forms individually, and then change the disabled attribute for all submit types

```js
function disableFormSubmit(form) {
    const buttons = form.querySelectorAll(
        'button[type="submit"], input[type="submit"]'
    );
    const disableButtons = () =>
        buttons.forEach(el => (el.disabled = form.matches(":invalid")));

    form.addEventListener("change", disableButtons);
    disableButtons();
}

document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach(disableFormSubmit);
```

```html
<form action="/">
    <legend>First form</legend>
    <input type="text" required> <br>
    <input type="Checkbox" required> required checkbox <br>
    <input type="submit">
    <button type="submit">Button submit</button>
</form>
<hr>
<form action="/">
    <legend>Second form</legend>
    <select required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select one</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select> <br>
    <input type="radio" required name="radio"> required radio <br>
    <input type="submit">
    <button type="submit">Button submit</button>
</form>
```

Personally i would go on an solution using only CSS as a visual cue, unless you need the disabled attribute